# Capybara custom Methods, where should these go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I was struggling with finding out how to find and select from the react-select library using Capybara until I stumbled onto this:
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/832

Super useful and it does work, someone mentioned a good way of doing it that works and I think it'd be useful to include that method definition.

However in rails where would something like this go? Ideally you wouldn't want it defined JUST in that test file. Would something like the `rails_helper` or `spec_helper` file be an appropriate place? or should someone be making a separate test_helper file for these helper functions? (Right now I have know `test_helper` file as im setting up the drivers in `rails_helper`

Im not really sure "automation wise" what the best convention is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using RSpec your `rails_helper.rb` usually has a line

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

This loads up all the rb files in the spec/support directory when starting up.  To add your methods you would add a new file, something like `spec/support/capybara_react_helper.rb` and in there put

```
module CapybaraReactHelepr
  def a_helper_method(...)
    ...
  end

  def another_helper(...)
    ...
  end
end
```

Then in your RSpec configuration (usually later in your rails_helper.rb) you can include those methods into feature tests

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   ...
   config.include CapybaraReactHelper, type: :feature
   ...
end
```

Comment: What exactly does the `type: feature` really do? Im used to seeing that on tests or is that only including that module on "feature" based tests?

Comment: @msmith1114 When defining a test that sets the type of the test (model, view, controller, request, feature, etc) or you can have it set automatically based on the directory the test is defined in. When used on the `include` statement it tells it when to include that module - in this case Capybaras DSL is usually only used in feature specs so it only makes sense to include the helper methods in the same type of test.